# Script file file not being loaded through ScriptLink custom action

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am having trouble with script link custom actions. I am building a SharePoint app, and I successfully added a site-scope custom action pointing to a script file in the Style Library, as I want this particular script to be injected to all the pages of my SharePoint site.

While it works in certain situations, the script link injection breaks without apparent reason under certain conditions. For example, when I arrive on my root web, the script will be injected. But, if I go to a certain link within this web (for example Home or Site Contents), the file that is supposed to be injected will simply not be fetched from the Style Library and therefore never be injected, resulting in an uncaught ReferenceError when I try to call one of the script's function. The weirdest part is that a page refresh through Ctrl+F5 will fetch the script file without any problem, regardless of the page's ability to originally fetch the script file when first accessed. It will keep the script until it is accessed through a link again.

I've read up on [Sharepoint caching](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/11/avoiding-bugs-from-cached-javascript.html), thinking it may be the cause of my problem, but the trouble is that these articles mostly talk about cache-induced errors when **updating** a file, while I am only trying to access it.

One thing to note is that, due to limitations, I am adding the script link custom action through code. Here's an example of what this kind of call currently looks like in my app:

```
context.Load(context.Site.UserCustomActions);
context.ExecuteQuery();

customAction.Name = "MyScriptLink";
customAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
customAction.Sequence = 100;
customAction.ScriptSrc = "~SiteCollection/Style Library/MySite/MyScript.js";

customAction.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

So, what's going on here ? Why is my script no injected on certain pages ? Why does a refresh on these exact same pages manage to fetch the file without any problem ?

Comment: can you try adding script using script tag instead of scriptlink see if it works? Also after that try adding attribute to scriptlink defer="false"

Comment: I don't know if that's what you meant, but I tried injecting come js code through the ScriptBlock property instead of trying to fetch a file through the ScriptSrc property, and the code gets injected everywhere, which means the custom action itself runs on every page.

Now, question is: why is it not fetching the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ! Three words: Minimum Download Strategy. Disable it, it messes with you page redirect behavior within a SharePoint site (either through code or through site settings)

Edit: If you still want MDS enabled on your site, there is a [solution](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx)

Comment: MDS means that scripts generally shouldn't need to be re-executed on an ajax/partial navigation - unfortunately there is also logic to explicit *delete* any javascript variables you have injected into the global "window" object, which can seriously break things if you're expecting them to be there. The solution in that case is to do what SharePoint itself does with its own objects, which is to set the property "__namespace" to true. E.g. 

window.varNeededByMyApp = { __namespace: true }.

That way SP won't delete it. Alternative ensure your injected var is of type Function (like jquery's $).